# Make progress bar compatible for all versions in Android

Tags: android, performance, android-progressbar

My problem is the `progressbar` is showing progress in *Gingerbread* and *Honeycomb* but it is not showing for *IceCreamSandwich*.
My xml code is as follows which I have set for `<android:progressdrawable>` in `progressbar`.

```
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:startColor="#FFFFFF" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
            <gradient
                android:endColor="#808080"
                android:startColor="#FF0000" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

And my minimumtarget version is 10 and maximumtargetversion is 14

Comment: Are you using custom theme for your application or just set the drawable in your xml?

Comment: Yes iam making custom theme

Answer (score -1):

Change targetversion to IceCreamSandwitch and that working.